# How to retrieve BLOB data from Oracle Client using Oledb driver in Vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I'm using oleDbConnection in order to Select a BLOB data from Oracle column, and I have to stick with this type of connection since all my application is using it.

After I used the following code, I got the error: unspecified error.

```
Dim pSelectCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand() 
Dim commandTextTemplate As String = "SELECT PICTURE FROM ALBUMS WHERE CODE= 4"
pSelectCommand.CommandText = commandTextTemplate
pSelectCommand.Connection = g_pOleDbConnection 
 
Dim fs As FileStream 
 
' Open the connection and read data into the DataReader.
If g_pOleDbConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then g_pOleDbConnection.Open()
 
Dim myReader As OleDbDataReader = pSelectCommand.ExecuteReader() 'Error is on this line

Do While (myReader.Read())
Dim byteArray As Byte() = (myReader(g_pfldAPicture))
fs = New FileStream("Album.bmp", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write)
fs.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
Loop
```

What can I try to fix this?

Comment: If you have an error, please type the error message!

Comment: I guess the error is mentioned in the main post...(Unspecifed error)..that`s it..

Comment: Try putting the fields and tables in brackets: `[PICTURE]`, `[ALBUMS]` and `[CODE]`.  Otherwise, double-check your field names.  You should refactor your code and always close the connection when you are done calling something, preferably using `using()` brackets.  The fact that you are checking the connection state is hinting at bigger problems to me.

Comment: LarsTech point is extremely important, Oracle is full of unmanaged resources and not deterministically finalising the dB connection will have an impact. Does the Unspecified Error have an inner exception? Usually Oracle gives you errors in the format ORA-00000? does the query run in TOAD or another sql EM tool?

Comment: @ LarsTech: I always close my connection even it is not shown here in this code, but for more rechecking I do check the connection state.

@Jeremy: The full unspecified error text I got is hereafter:

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unspecified error
Oracle error occurred, but error message could not be retrieved from Oracle.
Data type is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the same answer you got to your question on eggheadcafe and on CodeProject, ref:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/vb/14/10442149/how-to-retrieve-blob-data-from-oracle-client-using-oledb-driver-in-vb.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/368813/How-to-retrieve-BLOB-data-from-Oracle-Client-using

**Oracle Blobs aren't supported by OleDb. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244661
You have to use ADO.net instead.**

Edit: Hi there

I understood you, I was trying to say it nicely:

> Oracle 8.x-specific data types, such as CLOB, BLOB, BFILE, NCHAR,
>   NCLOB, and NVARCHAR2, are not supported.

ref: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244661

You need to use the [Oracle Provider for OLE DB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/ole_db/index.html) or better yet just use [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) (ODP.NET) for this BLOB reading operation.

Comment: Maybe you didn`t get me very well. I already checked the oracle connection type and it is successfully inserting binary data into the BLOB Oracle column using OLE object but the issue here is on reading the data from the BLOB column through OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader
and so I got an error (Unspecifed error) but Ole is mandatory in my case...thats why I need help...

Comment: yeah I'll try and help you, because its upnsupported as per my EDIT, in this case can you just resort to the file system for BLOB's or for this particular operation try and lobby to be able to use a different driver on the basis that this operation isn't supported with OleDB (non-oracle drivers)