# Parameter error displaying jpeg from byte array

Tags: vb.net, image, arrays, jpeg, bmp

The Image on the table is image type IMAGE/PJPEG.

I am pulling the BLOB image down, and I just need to display it either in an image box or as I'm trying now an image column.  However, I think my issue is due to the images being a JPEG.  Not sure how to fix this.

```
    For i As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

        Dim MTI_Image As Byte()

        STSQL = "Select IMAGE from mpcs.image_resource WHERE IMAGE_NAME = '01400010016.jpg'"

        rsMPCS = MPCS_SELECT_SQL(UCase(STSQL), rsMPCS)
        rsMPCS.Read()
        MTI_Image = rsMPCS("IMAGE")
        rsMPCS.Close()

        Using memory As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(MTI_Image)

            'Dim newImage = Image.FromStream(memory) 'didn't work
            Dim newImage As Bitmap = New Bitmap(memory) 'ERROR HERE

            Dim ColImage As New DataGridViewImageColumn
            Dim Img As New DataGridViewImageCell
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(ColImage)
            ColImage.HeaderText = "Image"
            ColImage.Name = "ColImg"
            Img.Value = newImage 
            DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells.Add(Img)

        End Using
    Next
```

This is how the image was inserted.

```
        Dim temp As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim FileStream As Stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead((temp))
        Dim array() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(temp)

        Using memory As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(array)
            Using reader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(memory)
```

And then the value used to insert was `reader.ReadByte`

Is there something here corrupting it somehow that is stopping me from displaying it?

**UPDATE**

So After using an image I know works (tried 5 I know works). I'm told there is no DATA for that Row/Column using the below code.

```
    For i As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

        STSQL = "Select IMAGE from MPCS.IMAGE_RESOURCE WHERE IMAGE_NAME = 'ThermalEtch.JPG'"

        rsMPCS = MPCS_SELECT_SQL(UCase(STSQL), rsMPCS)

        rsMPCS.Read()
        Dim byteImage() As Byte = rsMPCS("IMAGE") 'ERROR HERE.

        Using memory As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(byteImage)

            Dim newimage As Bitmap = New Bitmap(memory)

            Dim ColImage As New DataGridViewImageColumn
            Dim Img As New DataGridViewImageCell
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(ColImage)
            ColImage.HeaderText = "Image"
            ColImage.Name = "Image"
            Img.Value = newimage
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells.Add(Img)

        End Using
    Next
```

Here is MPCS_SLECT_SQL

```
Public Function MPCS_SELECT_SQL(ByVal strSQL As String, Optional ByRef readerObj As OleDbDataReader = Nothing) As OleDbDataReader 'ADODB.Recordset
    Try


        If OPEN_CONNECTIONS() = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to database.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            MPCS_SELECT_SQL = Nothing
            Exit Function
        Else


            If Not readerObj Is Nothing Then
                If readerObj.IsClosed - False Then readerObj.Close()
            End If
            Dim cmdMPCS As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conMPCS)

            MPCS_SELECT_SQL = cmdMPCS.ExecuteReader()
            cmdMPCS.Dispose()

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString & "     " & strSQL)
        Stop
        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: The `New Bitmap(memory)` code works for me with JPEG files, both baseline and progressive.  If I corrupt the data (e.g. write zeroes to the first 10 bytes) then I get "ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.".  So, I suspect that your image data is corrupt, either in the database or due to how you are loading the data.

Comment: Hi Mark, I thought maybe that could be the issue but wasn't sure.  I updated my post to show how it was added.  Maybe it sheds some light?

Comment: Better show us more of that insert code.  It doesn't look like you are saving all of the bytes if all you do is ReadByte.

Comment: What is that mysterious `MPCS_SELECT_SQL` method?

Comment: Just doing some of the OleDbDataReader behind the scenes in modmodule.  Used throughout the entire app, works fine. Never had an issue pulling anything out of the DB until this image.  I can go into the DB in SQL Developer and see that the image is there.

Comment: I added it to the post.

Comment: Maybe that's the issue?  I have to tell it somewhere that is image data and not a string its looking for?  Not sure.

Comment: Hope everyone had a good wknd, can you see anything else that would cause no image to be found?

Answer (score 0):

To read BLOB data from Oracle, you may need to use `GetBytes` and a buffer to build up your `MemoryStream`.  I don't have Oracle to test with, but something like this worked with SQL Server...

```
rsMPCS = MPCS_SELECT_SQL(UCase(STSQL), rsMPCS)
rsMPCS.Read()

Dim bufferSize = 10000
Using ms = New MemoryStream()
    Dim buffer(bufferSize - 1) As Byte
    Dim pos = 0L
    Dim bytesRead = rsMPCS.GetBytes(0, pos, buffer, 0, bufferSize)
    While bytesRead > 0
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, CInt(bytesRead))
        pos += bytesRead
        bytesRead = rsMPCS.GetBytes(0, pos, buffer, 0, bufferSize)
    End While
    Dim newimage = New Bitmap(ms)
    '... add to grid
End Using
```

I would put this in a helper method to clean up the code.

Comment: Hmm, I get the exact same error.  Not data exist for row column.  And I did go into SQL developer and verify the image exist for the one I'm testing with.

Comment: Hmm, from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10222439/2278086) - according to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/244661), depending on what provider you are using, BLOB may not be supported.  Is there a reason you are not using Oracle's native .NET client - [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) managed driver - instead?  Sorry, I don't have Oracle to test with, so perhaps not much more I can do.

Comment: I picked up this project from someone who had done about 75% worth of it maybe 5 years ago who's no longer here and ODP wasn't used throughout.  I don't use VB often, not sure if I can just use ODP in this instance since OraOLEDB is used elsewhere or not.

Comment: I would guess that OraOLEDB *does* support BLOB - the limitation noted above is probably only for Microsoft's Oracle provider... I just don't know how, sorry.